# How to open or switch between files in Android Studio using shortcuts

Tags: android-studio, flutter, shortcut

I'm using android studio for developing flutter apps. I use multiple files but find it hard to locate them in the project folder every time I have to open them (again).

Is there a way to open files in android studio with a shortcut?

original post for reference:
i'm using android studio for develop flutter app

i usually , open pubspect.yaml file when I add packages.

i added yaml file at favorite folder ,
but it little bit annoying to click it to open it.

so , is there a way to solve this little problem?
i tried macro but didn't work.

====
If you see this message, then your question was automatically blocked by the server. All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for some basic indicators of a good, complete question. Check to make sure that your question has the following:
A clear title.
A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.
Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut I use to navigate is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

As shown in android studio [key_maps](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html#custom). You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will be used to navigate through files.

If it is easy for you then, Go to `Settings -> KeyMap`. And, you can edit your own key shortcuts. Specifically, to your question:

You can search `navigate`, you will be able to see `File` and its corresponding shortcut key, there you can edit another shortcut key too.